# How to import packages while waiting for user responce in Python

Tags: python, import, parallel-processing

I have written a Python script that itself is fast, but it takes quite a bit of time to start up due to multiple imports. Often on the first start up it may take >10 seconds to load (especially on slower computers), though on second, third and further start ups it usually takes much less time to load. I would like to reduce the loading time as much as possible.

The general structure of the script is as follows:

```
# Necessary imports that take a long time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("Welcome message.")
rsp = input('Enter value: ')

# Other code
result = 42

print(f"Output result: {result}")
```

Notice that right after importing all the necessary libraries, I ask the user for input and wait for their response. I wonder if it is possible to import all the libraries while I am waiting for the user input.

What I have tried to do was to ask for the user input within a helper thread and import all the libraries in the main thread like so:

```
import threading
from time import perf_counter

print('Starting')
USER_RSP = None  # global variable used to get the user response from the thread


def get_rsp():
    global USER_RSP
    USER_RSP = input(" > ")
    print('Response received')

# Create and initialize the thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=get_rsp)
thread.start()

# Necessary imports that take a long time
print('Importing matplotlib')
t1 = perf_counter()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t2 = perf_counter()
print(f'It took {t2-t1:.3f} seconds to import matplotlib.')
print('Importing pandas')
t1 = perf_counter()
import pandas as pd
t2 = perf_counter()
print(f'It took {t2-t1:.3f} seconds to import pandas.')
print('Importing numpy')
t1 = perf_counter()
import numpy as np
t2 = perf_counter()
print(f'It took {t2-t1:.3f} seconds to import numpy.')

# Await for the thread to stop execution
thread.join()

# Other code
result = 42

print(f"Output result: {result}")
```

Unfortunately, it did not work, because it seems that `input` blocks the execution in both the main thread and the helper thread.
When executed, I get the following messages.

```
Starting
 > Importing matplotlib
12
Response received
It took 3.869 seconds to import matplotlib.
Importing pandas
It took 0.393 seconds to import pandas.
Importing numpy
It took 0.000 seconds to import numpy.
Output result: 42

Process finished with exit code 0
```

At first the execution stops at " > Importing matplotlib" until I type "12". Only afterwards the libraries are imported. Removing all the `print` functions has no effect, just in case you are wondering.

So, my questions are:

1. Why did my solution not work and what can be done to make it work?
2. Are there any other ways to reduce the time it takes to import all the essential libraries?